# Monitoramento de diretorio PHP

Tags: php

Preciso executar um script sempre que for enviado um arquivo para um determinado diretório.

Meu servidor irá receber um arquivo via `ftp_put`, e sempre que esse arquivo chegar, eu preciso executar um script.

Encontrei a extensão [FAM (File Alteration Monitor)](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.fam.php) do PHP porém não sei se utilizá-la seria a melhor abordagem.

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow! Procure enriquecer a sua pergunta, adicionando o contexto que você está utilizando e também alguma tentativa. Da maneira que está a sua pergunta, a resposta é **"Depende"**. Detalhes em [tour] e [ask]

Comment: O que já posso adiantar como reposta é que ele precisa ser instalado separadamente como uma extensão (Se estiver utilizando um server compartilhado, esqueça) e também não funciona em ambiente Windows: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.fam.php

Comment: @gmsantos não estou usando utilizando server compartilhado e nem windows. Vou tentar ser um pouco mais especifico.